# STa"M on which children disagree

Tags: halacha, safrus, safek

There is a halacha that if one is unsure if certain letters of STa"M (Sefer Torah/Tefillin/Mezuza) are of the right length, one can ask a child.

What happens if there was a doubt in a letter in a tefillin, one sofer asked a child, the child misread it, and then afterwards someone else showed it (not knowing that it was already shown) to another child and the second child read it correctly?

- Can the second man fulfill his obligation with this Tefillin?
- Is it a Safek (so if any of the two sofrim put on tfillin with these Parshios, they would have to put on another pair without a blessing)?
- If this happened a few times (this ksav was shown to a few children), and all read it wrong except for one, could that one later on (assuming this parsha was unfixed) claim "leshitaso" and wear this tefillin without a Bracha?

Comment: +1. You can also ask if one child said it right and *then* another said otherwise.

Comment: Then you wouldn't have question 1

Comment: Wouldn't you, though about the other man?

Comment: @msh210 then there is no man 2

Comment: I meant the case would be: One man asked a child, who said it right, and another (not knowing it was already shown) asked another child, who read it wrong. Exact parallel to your case.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [Keset HaSofer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sofer#Texts_teaching_sofrut), by Rabbi [Shlomo Ganzfried](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shlomo_Ganzfried), rules ([6:4](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=8308&st=&pgnum=30)) that when multiple children disagree about the reading of a letter we follow the majority. I suppose if there are only 2 children, we wait עד שיבוא השלישי ויכריע ביניהם -- until a third one comes and resolves the contradiction.